# How to check in single event if two objects are clicked at the same time in libGDX?

Tags: android, libgdx

I am newbie to libGDX and I have written two functions for touchdown,

```
    LockerKeyHalfImage.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("clickrd Locker>>>>>>>>");
              return false;
        }
        });

    MasterKeyHalfImage.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("clickrd Master>>>>>>>>");
              return false;
        }
});
```

My problem is to check if these two images are clicked at the same time (multi-touch detection). I tried to use the following lines without success:

```
 InputMultiplexer im = new InputMultiplexer();
      //  GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(ui);
         //   im.addProcessor(gd);
            im.addProcessor(ui);
            Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(im);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what are lockerkeyhalfimage and MasterKey... ? are they actors ? and are they in the same stage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your listeners, instead of returning `false`, do something like this:

```
int numTouches = 0;

LockerKeyHalfImage.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.println("clickrd Locker>>>>>>>>");
          numTouches += 1;
    }
 });

MasterKeyHalfImage.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.println("clickrd Master>>>>>>>>");
          numTouches += 1;
    }
});
```

Now, to check for multi-touch, just expose and check that `numTouches >= 1`. That means there were two or more things touched at the same time.

Also, you should be returning `true`, not `false`, if you've already handled clicks in your multiplexer methods.

Comment: @Zadalaxmi thanks for coming back (in January!) and marking this as the right answer -- glad to know it did help you.